# gulp-sass not importing scss files

Tags: css, sass, gulp, gulp-sass, node-sass

I'm on node version 11 (although I've tried 10 and 9), I'm using gulp version 3.9.1 and gulp-cli version 2.0.1, gulp-sass version 4.0.2, and node-sass version 4.11.2.  Here is my very simple scss file:

```
@import "normalize-scss/sass/normalize";

h1 {
  color: red;
}
```

Here is a dead simple gulpfile I am testing with:

```
var gulp        = require('gulp'),
    sass        = require('gulp-sass'),
    connect     = require('gulp-connect');

gulp.task('sass', function(){
  gulp.src('src/scss/style.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('src/css'));
});

gulp.task('serve', ['sass'], function () {
  connect.server();
});

gulp.task('default', ['serve']);
```

When I start the server with a bad import path, like say `@import "normalize-scss/asdf/sass/normalize";`, I get an error saying the patch can't be found.  However, when I use the actual import path and start my task (like what's above), I get no errors, yet I only get this in my style.css file:

```
h1 {
  color: red; }
```

I've been banging my head against this for an hour.  Any clues?

Comment: It sounds like the problem is occurring at the SASS level, although I don't see anytning wrong with your scss file.  SUGGESTIONS: 1) Look [here](https://blog.codepen.io/2016/02/15/sass-debug-and-warn-output-to-the-console/) for some tips on SASS debugging; 2) Please clarify exactly what you *EXPECT* to see in your "my.css"

Comment: Do you use both 'sass' and ' scss' folders as you have above?

Comment: Only regarding this bower dependency do I use a "sass" folder, usually I use a "scss" folder, plus I've mixed folder names countless times in the past.

Answer (score 1):

It's my own fault; normalize.scss as it is found at https://github.com/appleboy/normalize.scss requires an `@include normalize();` to start working.  I guess I had spent so much time on gulp debugging that I lost track of the simple things.